# Remove a page from Navigation Stack

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have this application schema :

```
[List Page] -> [Detail Page] -> [ShareOnFacebook Page]
                     ^__________________|
```

1. The user select an `Item` in the `[List Page]`
2. The user may or may not click a `Share` button if he or she does, the application navigates to a `[ShareOneFacebook page]` which displays a Facebook Login Form, posts a message and navigates back
3. The user navigates back.

If the user shared on facebook, it will "repost" the message, because the application store the session so it will navigate back to ShareOnFacebook, and then back to my Detail page.

If the user didn't share, he goes back to the List Page.

How can I "ommit" the ShareOnFacebook page in my navigation stack ?

Comment: it works, but its quite the hack. I like Androids model of being able to call finish and then move, works nicely

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Try this:** Call `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();` in the `OnNavigatedTo` method. This will remove the previous page from the stack. In my opinion the trick with `Navigation.GoBack();` is not satisfying because it shows the page to remove for a short time.

Note: Works only with Windows Phone OS 7.1 (Mango) SDK

Comment: Thanks, I changed the approved answer. My original question was before Mango, but I figure new people will need this answer now

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar situation in my app, i solve it with a very simple solution.

If you want to "skip" a page in your backstack, place some logic in the NavigatedTo() function of that page.

For example: you can have a bool that you set to true when you post to facebook, and then place the following code in the NavigatedTo() function of the ShareOnFacebook page.

Here is pseudo code:

`if (alreadyPosted)
     Navigation.GoBack();`

The GoBack() function will skip this page and return to the previous one, the user will never see the page.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at simple library i wrote for such purposes:
http://navcoerce.codeplex.com/

```
var fluent = new FluentNavigation(RootFrame);                          

fluent.WhenNavigatedTo<MainPage>()                                     
      .ThenTo<LoginPage>()                                             
      .ThenToAnyPage()                                                 
      .RemoveEntriesFromBackStack(1);                                  

fluent.WhenNavigatedTo<MainPage>()                                     
      .ThenTo<LoginPage>()                                             
      .ThenTo<RegisterPage>()                                          
      .ThenTo<PaymentPage>()                                           
      .RemoveEntriesFromBackStackTill<MainPage>();                     

fluent.WhenNavigatedTo<MainPage>()                                     
      .ThenTo<SecondPage>()                                            
      .ThenTo<RegisterPage>()                                          
      .ThenOptionallyTo<ForgotPasswordPage>()                          
      .ThenToAnyPage()                                                 
      .RemoveEntriesFromBackStackTill<MainPage>();                     

fluent.WhenNavigatingTo<PaymentPage>()                                 
      .RedirectTo<LoginPage>();                                        

fluent.WhenNavigatingTo<PaymentPage>()                                 
      .If(() => false)                                                 
      .RedirectWithReturnUri<LoginPage>("ReturnUri");
```

Comment: Hi, is the project still alive?

Comment: Vitalii, currently i don't develop for WP so i don't make any changes to the library. But feel free to fork the project, i'll accept any changes that can help you and other users.

Comment: Maybe a bit later - for now i'm looking for proven solution to deal with navigation. I have main pivot leak, and when navigating on it, i have 2 views. Somehow, using fluent didnt help in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the new [Nonlinear Navigation Service recipe](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx)

Download it from http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/nln-serv-wp7

Answer (score 1):

I use the `removeBackEntry` method on the `NavigationService` Class. I also use this as a way to setup my own splash screens

```
        private void BWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // switch screen 
        NavigationService.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(NavigationServiceNavigated);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/main.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }

    void NavigationServiceNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted an example for the same issue [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519096/how-to-skip-a-page-in-back-navigation-in-windows-phone-7)

The Nonlinear Navigation Service Matt linked to essentially does the same thing but would probably be better than my simple example.