# Programmatically back out of first page of your application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a login page which is shown on first launch. After the user puts in his credentials he is taken to the main page of the application. At this point, if the user presses the back key I want it to skip the login page and exit. I tried what was suggested here: [Remove a page from Navigation Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440605/remove-a-page-from-navigation-stack) (in OnNavigatedTo, use NavigationService.GoBack()) but it throws an exception because there is nothing else in the back stack. I read some other places that not handling exceptions is basically the only way to close the app...

The problem with this method of closing the app is, well other than being a hack, it doesn't hit  Application_Closing() so my state isn't saved.

Anyone know how I can skip the login page when hitting the back key, save state, and exit the application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is becoming a huge problem with Navigation in WP7 - many folks are complaining about this same type of issue. The key to remember is that Navigation mimics navigation of a website - it acts a lot less like UserForms and more like web pages and their static history.

The easiest way around this which is both transparent to your users and easy for you is to make that first login page you are reference as User Control that sits on top of your actual main page (i.e. don't use a `phone:PhoneApplicationPage` for your login page - just a control that is part of your main page `phone:PhoneApplicationPage`). Use a boolean in your `OnNavigatedTo` on the main page that says "if user is not logged in, display login control, otherwise, just show main page."

On saving state (i.e. tombstoning), ask another question as that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

The general best practice is to not use a page for anything you dont want in the navigation stack.

In my case i chose to use a Popup to host my Login Control.  I pop it from my mainpage if they are not logged in.  If they are i dont show it.  This way if they are not logged in and hit back, they exit the app.  However if they are logged in and also on teh main page, they see their data, and if they hit back they also exit the app (not see the login page).

Answer (score 0):

For the login / home page scenario one thing you can do is on successful login rather than navigating to the home page you call "GoBack", this will take them back to the home page, but pop the login page off the navigation stack and allow the user to exit the app on the next press of the back button.